# How to start a python lemmatizer for Malay language with a dataset?

Tags: python, lemmatization

I have a dataset and I want to perform Malay language lemmatizer. Can guide me how to do this project?

What is the code to create a lemmatizer for Malay language. It can aslo allow user to enter words and determine the lemma of the word entered.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can the malaya library developed by HUSEIN

https://malaya.readthedocs.io/en/latest/load-stemmer.html

```py
import malaya
naive = malaya.stem.naive()

naive.stem("saya nak makan")
```